# Repeat sampling loop in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to do random sampling from a data frame, where sampling is conditional on the property of the item already sampled. In the code below, I'm trying to sample an item from "snr", then a random "correct" value corresponding to the first sampled "snr". I then want to sample a larger or smaller "snr" value based on the value of "correct". This process should be repeated 'y' times and show an output of two vectors, "snr" and "correct" of length y.

Currently, if the function is working my R window stops responding and it never stops, or I get a variety of errors.

```
snr=c(2,4,6,2,4,6,2,4,6,2,4,6);correct=c(0.2,0.8,0.3,0.7,0.4,0.6,1,1,0,0.1,0.9,0)
data$snr=snr; data$correct=correct

samplesub2<-function(data.frame,y){ ### x is data frame, y is number of samples ###
  repeat{
    snrS<- sample(data.frame$snr,1,replace=TRUE)
    correctS<- sample(data.frame$correct[data.frame$snr==snrS], 1, replace=TRUE)

    if (correctS>0.5){
      snrS<-sample(data.frame$snr[data.frame$snr==snrS+2],1,replace=TRUE)
      correctS<- sample(data.frame$correct[data.frame$snr==snrS], 1, replace=TRUE)
    }

    else if (correctS<0.5){
      snrS<- sample(data.frame$snr[data.frame$snr==snrS-2]),1,replace=TRUE)
      correctS<- sample(data.frame$correct[data.frame$snr==snrS], 1, replace=TRUE)
    }

    if(length(snrS<y)
      break
  }
  return(c(snrS,correctS))
}
```

Comment: You have two typos in your code: `if(length(snrS<y)`  and `sample(data.frame$snr[data.frame$snr==snrS-2]),1,replace=TRUE)`

Comment: Cheers, good spot.

Answer (score 0):

The below code would divide the iris dataset randomly into 5 subsets with 30 samples each 5 times. In total, 5 Groups with 5 subsets each. Total 25 subsets from 5 groups.

```
 for(i in 1:5){
 iris_grp=split(iris,sample(rep(1:5,30)))
 names(iris_grp) <- paste("iris",i,c("A","B","C","D","E"),sep="")
 list2env(iris_grp, envir = .GlobalEnv)
 print(iris_grp)
 for(i in seq_along(iris_grp)) {
 write.table(iris_grp[[i]], paste(names(iris_grp)[i], ".txt", sep =    ""), 
        col.names = T, row.names = T, sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
 }
 i=i+1
 }
```

Hope this example would help.